# NDK - Arrays Allocatio/deallocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, android-ndk, native

I want to copy bitmap pixels to a 3D array, and from this 3d array I allocate new arrays for a specific image processing algorithm. my code will involve the use of MD arrays the most. I want an efficient way to do that, fast and without memory overhead/leaks...

here is my current Cpp code :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>
#include "com_example_ndk_MainActivity.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {

    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t alpha;
} argb;



JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_ndk_MainActivity_invert(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject bitmapcolor,jobject bitmapgray)
{
    AndroidBitmapInfo infocolor;
    void* pixelscolor;
    AndroidBitmapInfo infogray;
    void* pixelsgray;
    int ret;
    int y;
    int x;
    int i,j;

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapcolor, &infocolor)) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapgray, &infogray)) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapcolor, &pixelscolor)) < 0) {
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapgray, &pixelsgray)) < 0) {
    }

    // copy pixels to array


    int* arr;
    arr = new int[infocolor.height * infocolor.width * 3* sizeof(int)];

    for (y=0;y<infocolor.height;y++) {
        argb * line = (argb *) pixelscolor;
        argb * grayline = (argb *) pixelsgray;
        for (x=0;x<infocolor.width;x++) {


            arr[x * (infocolor.height * 3) + y * 3 + 1] = line[x].red;
            arr[x * (infocolor.height * 3) + y * 3 + 2] = line[x].green;
            arr[x * (infocolor.height * 3) + y * 3 + 3] = line[x].blue;
            }

        pixelscolor = (char *)pixelscolor + infocolor.stride;
    }

    //do the algorithm on the array of pixels here--------

    //the store the new pixels in the returned bitmap
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapcolor);

    for (y=0;y<infocolor.height;y++) {
            argb * grayline = (argb *) pixelsgray;
            for (x=0;x<infocolor.width;x++) {
                grayline[x].alpha = 255;
                grayline[x].red = arr[x * (infocolor.height * 3) + y * 3 + 1];
                grayline[x].green = arr[x * (infocolor.height * 3) + y * 3 + 2];
                grayline[x].blue = arr[x * (infocolor.height * 3) + y * 3 + 3];
                }

            pixelsgray = (char *)pixelsgray + infocolor.stride;
    }

    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapgray);

}
```

Comment: you cant expect people to click around and follow your question/answer chain.  Please try rephrasing your new complete quesion

Comment: Why are you using a `jint *` if what you're pointing at are `double`s?

Comment: if java arrays have contiguous storage guarantee, you can try treating the 3d array as 1d.

Comment: @user3528438 can you explain more?

Comment: get the pointer to a[0][0][0] and iterate to the end

Comment: @user3528438 I'm not really good at c/c++ stuff,  I would appreciate if you answer with code 

Comment: @user3528438 No, Java, .NET, and similar environments don't have multidimensional arrays. They have an array of objects, which is an object, and the array is mutable in that its elements can be swapped out. Ergo, array of arrays and the possibility of "jagged arrays."

Comment: Guys the code works only for small sized arrays. For larger ones I get unpinnedpremitivearray error. Why?